# Magento Assign to group if .edu email

Tags: php, magento

In magento I would like to assign customers with .edu email addresses to a particular group when they register a new account.

So far I have followed this guide: http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/automatically-set-magento-customer-group

I'm just looking to change the last bit up. Instead of the customer selecting their flavor, I would like to assign them to group 4 if their email address ends in .edu

I have the following so far

```
<?php

class College_Customer_Model_Customer_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
/*
 * observer for the customer saved event
 */
public function customer_save_before( $observer )
{
    try {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        $email = $observer->getCustomerEmail();

        if( (substr($email, strrpos($email, ".")+1) == "edu") )
            $customer->setData( 'group_id', 4 ); 
        else
            $customer->setData( 'group_id', 1); 
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        Mage::log( "customer_save_before observer failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
    }
}
}

?>
```

I have tested

```
(substr($email, strrpos($email, ".")+1) == "edu")
```

and I don't think that is the problem. I'm wondering if I'm calling the Customer Email wrong.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you all

Bass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you have customer email? Try this:

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
$email = $customer->getEmail();
```